# how to change the div value with a counter

Tags: html

I don't understand why this function does not change the value of num every time I press the button. basically i wanted to make a counter that adds one to the div every time i press the button.

```
        <div class="elements" id="txtthrow">0</div>
        <button class="button1" id="buttonNewHand" onclick="newFaceTot()">new<br>number</button>
```

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
            refthrow = document.getElementById("txtthrow");
        

        function newFaceTot(){
            numberChanged();
        }

        function numberChanged(){
            var num = parseInt(refthrow.value, 10);
            refthrow.innerHTML = changeNumber(num);
        }

        function changeNumber(num){
            num = num + 1;
            return num;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only form (e.g. input/select/textarea) elements have a value. For other elements use `innerHTML` or `innerText` to get the content.

```js
const refthrow = document.getElementById("txtthrow");


function newFaceTot() {
  numberChanged();
}

function numberChanged() {
  var num = parseInt(refthrow.innerText, 10);
  refthrow.innerHTML = changeNumber(num);
}

function changeNumber(num) {
  num = num + 1;
  return num;
}
```

```html
<div class="elements" id="txtthrow">0</div>
<button class="button1" id="buttonNewHand" onclick="newFaceTot()">new<br>number</button>
```

Therefore the value attribute was `undefined`. And `parseInt(undefined)` is `NaN` (not a number).